# How to keep the data of a form after hiding it

Tags: vba, winforms, show-hide

The user enters data in Form1 for example his name and phone number, he clicks on the "next" button that opens Form2 and Hide Form1, if he clicks on the "back" button I want the program to show Form1 with the data he entered before

The code for the "Next" Button in Form1:

```
Private Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click
    Dim MyForm As New Form2
    MyForm.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

What should I do in order to keep the data the user entered if he comes back to Form1?

The code for the "Previous" button in Form2:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing. You just hid the Form, so everything is still there. Or, are you creating a new Form1 when the user clicks the *previous* Button? Btw, why didn't you post that code? Btw2, this is VB.Net, not VBA.

Comment: Yep my bad, here is the code
`Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub`

Comment: Please, update your question with the new code, don't post it in comments. -- It appears that you have a problem in preserving the data entered in Form2 (since you close it) rather than in Form1 (since you're not closing that Form).

Comment: If this is some sort of *Wizard* Window, think about using a TabControl with a hidden header and TabPages that show UserControls rather than Forms, so you just need to move from a TabPage to another, the direction is not that relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could use is to only the use the [DEFAULT INSTANCES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-forms-object) of your Forms.  These are accessed by using only the name of the Form, WITHOUT ever using the "New" keyword.

You're doing exactly that in Form2 when you show Form1 with:

```
Form1.Show()
```

This works because Form1 is your startup object and VB.Net used the default instance to start the application.

You could do the same thing in Form1, to show Form2:

```
' ... code in Form1 ...
Private Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click
    Form2.Show() ' show the default instance of Form2 (do NOT use the "new" keyword)
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Just make sure in all places you `Hide()` the current form instead of closing it.

You can access the properties/fields of the default instances using the same syntax to show them, using only their name.  For example, here is a made up value being accessed on Form2:

```
Dim userName As String = Form2.txtAddress1.Text
```

This assumes that Form2 was previously displayed and populated by the user.  You could access the Forms from anywhere in the code using this type of syntax.

If you want to implement your own "default instance" mechanism, you could use Shared members in a class:

```
Public Class WizardForms
    Public Shared F1 As New Form1
    Public Shared F2 As New Form2
    Public Shared F3 As New Form3
End Class
```

Then you could use code like this to display one:

```
WizardForms.F2.Show()
```

This would work as long as you are only HIDING the forms.  If you allow the user to close the Forms (or close them via code), then you'd need extra code to make sure they get recreated as needed.